# How to consider previous elements when mapping over a list?

Tags: haskell

I'm stuck at making a function in Haskell wich has to do the following:

For each integer in a list check how many integers in front of it are smaller.

```
smallerOnes [1,2,3,5] will have the result [(1,0), (2,1), (3,2), (5,3)]
```

At the moment I have:

```
smallerOnes :: [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
smallerOnes [] = []
smallerOnes (x:xs) =
```

I don't have any clue on how to tackle this problem. Recursion is probably the way of thinking here but at that point I'm losing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Data.List (inits)
smallerOnes :: [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
smallerOnes xs = zipWith (\x ys -> (x, length $ filter (< x) ys)) xs (inits xs)
```

Comment: Stared blind at the first answer of Will Ness, turned out that this answer solves my whole problem.(after the Electric Coffee update).  Thanks all

Answer (score 4):

It is beneficial here not to start with a base case, but rather with a main case.

Imagine we've already processed half the list. Now we are faced with the rest of the list, say `x:xs`. We want to know how many integers *"before it"* are smaller than `x`; so we need to know these elements, say `ys`: `length [y | y<-ys, y<x]` will be the answer.

So you'll need to use an internal function that will maintain the prefix `ys`, produce the result for each `x` and return them in a list:

```
smallerOnes :: [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
smallerOnes [] = []
smallerOnes xs = go [] xs
  where
      go ys (x:xs) = <result for this x> : <recursive call with updated args>
      go ys []     = []
```

This can also be coded using some built-in higher-order functions, e.g.

```
scanl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> [a]
```

which will need some post-processing (like `map snd` or something) or more directly with

```
mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])
```

[`mapAccumL` is in `Data.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL).

Comment: This answer helps me alot! Only thing where i'm still stuck on is this part: go ys [] = ....

Comment: When i put it like this:                              smallerOnes:: [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
smallerOnes [] = []
smallerOnes xs = go [] xs
  where
      go ys (x:xs) = length [y | y<-ys, y<x]
      go ys [] = []                                           I'll get a lot of errors..

Comment: you should return a list of pairs, `[(Int,Int)]`. You create a pair as e.g. `(4,5)`, and a list of pairs as `(4,5) : go <...> <...>`.