# Point-free equivalent

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I have this function [from another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26357098/1838505),

```
f :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
f xs = zipWith (\x ys -> (x, length $ filter (< x) ys)) xs (inits xs)
```

I'm trying to write it in point-free style,

```
f = flip (zipWith (\x -> (,) x . length . filter (< x))) =<< inits
```

Is it possible to get rid of that x ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule: if a variable turns up more than once in an expression, *it's probably not a good idea to make it point-free*. If you're determined however, the least unreadable way is with the `Arrow` combinators, because that makes it pretty clear where the data flow is "split". For the `xs` I'd write

```
  uncurry (zipWith (...)) . (id &&& inits)
```

For `x`, the same method yields

```
  zipWith ( curry $ uncurry(,) . (fst &&& length . uncurry filter . first(>)) )
```

This is even longer than the `(->)`-monad solution that you've used and lambdabot suggests, but it looks far more organised.

Answer (score 8):

It's *possible*, but absolutely not worth the pain. To directly answer your question, LambdaBot on FreeNode reports:

```
f = flip (zipWith (liftM2 (.) (,) ((length .) . filter . flip (<)))) =<< inits
```

At this point the function has lost whatever clarity it had, and has become unmaintainable. Here you'd do much better to introduce real names. Remember, just because we can make things point free does not mean we should.

Answer (score 5):

The point of pointfree style is not just *omitting* names for values, but *preferring* names for functions. This is significantly easier to do when you use very small definitions. Of course any code is going to become unreadable if you inline everything and don’t use good names.

So let’s start with your original function, and split it into a few smaller definitions.

```
f xs = zipWith combine xs (inits xs)
combine x xs = (x, countWhere (< x) xs)
countWhere f xs = length (filter f xs)
```

Now we can easily make these definitions pointfree in a readable way.

```
f = zipWith combine <*> inits
  where combine = compose (,) countLessThan

compose = liftA2 (.)
countLessThan = countWhere . flip (<)
countWhere = length .: filter
(.:) = (.) . (.)
```

Using names *judiciously* and preferring composition over application allows us to factor code into small, easily understood definitions. Named parameters are the equivalent of `goto` for data—powerful, but best used to build reusable higher-level structures that are easier to understand and use correctly. These compositional combinators such as `(.)` and `<*>` are to data flow what `map`, `filter`, and `fold` are to control flow.

Comment: me personally, I'm quickly lost in this forest of names. The point to point-free, for me, is not having to name what's not important. Not only arguments, but interim functions too - *mostly* the interim functions.

Comment: @WillNess: Yeah, I guess you should give names mainly to functions you expect to reuse—but you’ll also reuse them more if they’re available because you named them, so it’s a tradeoff.

Answer (score 4):

My stab at it:

```
f :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
f = zip <*> ((zipWith $ (length .) . filter . (>)) <*> inits)
```

Here I replaced `(<)` with `(>)` to have `(length .) . filter . (>)` as a function with arguments in the right order: `a->[a]->Int`. Passing it to `zipWith`, we get `[a]->[[a]]->[Int]`.

Assuming we have `[a]` on input, we can see this as `f ([[a]]->[Int])` for `Applicative ((->) [a])`, which can be combined with `inits :: f [[a]]` with `<*> :: f ([[a]]->[Int])->f [[a]]->f [Int]`. This gives us `[a]->[Int]`, now need to consume both `[a]` and `[Int]` in parallel. `zip` is already of the right type: `[a]->[Int]->[(a,Int)]` to apply with `<*>`.

Comment: ah, nice. this completes the *follow-the-data* line of thought (re: the double-`<*>`). This way, there's no messing with the `curry`/`uncurry`.

Comment: @WillNess yes, first I wrote `zip <*> ...` but used `(=<<)` instead of `<*>` with `inits`. Without mentioning monad, it looks almost like a rhyme about "Reader" Applicative.

Comment: @WillNess :) just too excited how neat it looks. It was a great exercise for me, not used to looking at functions like that.

Answer (score 3):

Not saying I recommend this, but the King of Pointfree is `Control.Arrow`

```
import Control.Arrow

-- A special version of zipWith' more amenable to pointfree style
zipWith' :: ((a, b) -> c) -> ([a], [b]) -> [c]
zipWith' = uncurry . zipWith . curry

f :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
f = zipWith' (fst &&& (length <<< uncurry filter <<< first (>))) <<< id &&& inits
```

Let me reclarify here—I really don't recommend this unless your intention is to somehow generalize the kind of arrow your program is operating in (e.g. into Arrowized FRP perhaps).

Comment: with `zipWith' = uncurry . zipWith . curry`

Answer (score 2):

With the well-known

```
 (f .: g) x y = f (g x y)
```

it is a semi-readable

```
zipWith (curry (fst &&& uncurry (length .: (filter . flip (<))) )) <*> inits
--     \(x,ys) -> (x ,           length  ( (filter . flip (<)) x ys) )
```

Using `Control.Applicative` (`f <*> g $ x = f x (g x)`, the **S** combinator), and `Control.Arrow` (as others, but a little bit differently).

Comment: Is that `.:` well-known enough to be part of any standard package?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure. You can try Hoogle for its type. There's a [tag:dot-operator], or something, on SO, too.

Comment: Ah, I just found [`Data.Composition`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-1.0.1.0/docs/Data-Composition.html) (by coincidence, Hoogle did not find `.:`)

Comment: @Bergi [FPComplete's Hoogle finds it by its type](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=%28c+-%3E+d%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+b+-%3E+d&env=ghc-7.8-stable-14.09) or even [just by its name, `.:`](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=.%3A&env=ghc-7.8-stable-14.09).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew that installation - the ["official" one requires me to know the package name](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=.:+%2Bcomposition)